# Error in the code when working with arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Hy!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?
package studing;

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int[] ar1 = new int[50];
        for(i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++)
        {
            ar1[i] = i * 2 + 1;
            System.out.print(ar1[i] + " ");
        };

        System.out.println();

        for(i = ar1.length; i > -1; i--)
        {
            ar1[i] = i * 2 - 1;
            System.out.print(ar1[i]);
        };

    }

}
```

After compiling the console displays:

> 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49
>   51 53 55 57 59 61 63 65 67 69 71 73 75 77 79 81 83 85 87 89 91 93 95
>   97 99
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   50    at studing.Array.main(Array.java:18)

I want the output console in the second row `99 97 95 93 ...`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You start at `ar1.length` in your second loop, which is out of bounds.

To get it to work, you need to start at `ar1.length-1`, which is the maximum index for your array.
This is because arrays are 0-based in Java, as noted in the comments by @Maroun Maroun.

Comment: Clarification: Because arrays in Java are zero-based.

Comment: Thank you! Corrected the mistake. Now, the console displays everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The first time the second for loop runs, i = 50 (the initial value), which is beyond the end of the array. This value is used before the index update of i--, so ar1[50] is out of bounds (proper indexes are 0 to 49 for a 50 element array).

Comment: Thank you! Corrected the mistake. Now, the console displays everything correctly.